# How to pass function argument by reference in Circom?

Tags: circuit, circom, zkp, zk-snark

How to pass function argument by reference in the [circom circuit language](https://github.com/iden3/circom)?

I'm trying to do the following:

```
pragma circom 2.0.0;


function increment(foo) {
    foo++;
}

template MyTemplate() {
    signal input a;
    signal output b;

    var foo;
    foo = 0;

    increment(foo);
    log(foo);


    // ...
}

component main = MyTemplate();
```

I expect `log(pos)` to output 1, but I'm getting 0. Is there a certain way I need to pass `pos` into `increment` so that it can modify the variable by reference?

Comment: Not sure if the right stack exchange site, happy to close.

Comment: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/ might be more appropriate for ZKP-related questions. The official docs only illustrate the usage of functions with return values and don't mention passing args by reference, so you could try to define a new variable that receives the result of the increment and then use it inside log().

Comment: I want to return two results out of `increment` function in the future, so passing by reference is more appropriate rather than returning the result. I don't think circom allows me to return tuples either. I've looked into making a template, but those seems to be unwieldy. Is it okay to repost the question verbatim to crypto.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to use the C preprocessor to generate circom code, so now I have:

```
main.circom: 
    cpp -P maintpl.circom > main.circom
```

in my Makefile

and

```
#define increment(foo) foo++
```

in my circom code.